# HTML Table cellspacing or padding just top / bottom

Tags: html, html-table

Can you have cellpadding or spacing just on the top/ bottom as opposed to all (T, B, L, R) ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

CSS?

```
td {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

There is css:

```
table { border-spacing: 40px 10px; }
```

for 40px wide and 10px high

Answer (score 10):

Cellspacing is all around the cell and cannot be changed (i.e. if it's set to one, there will be 1 pixel of space on all sides). Padding can be specified discreetly (e.g. `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`, `padding-left`, and `padding-right;` or `padding: [top] [right] [bottom] [left];`).

Answer (score 3):

This might be a little better:

```
td {
  padding:2px 0;
}
```